# How to write unit-test-driven code without PropertyChanged handlers everywhere

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mvvm, data-binding, tdd

Let's say I've got this spec:

```
Given a UserProfile with some User and some UserPrefs
When ShowEmail in UserPrefs is set to true
Then the Email field in UserProfile should be the User's Email
And when ShowEmail in UserPrefs is set to false
Then the Email field in UserProfile should be "Hidden"
```

Cool. Simple enough; I'll just do this in `UserProfileViewModel`:

```
public string Email
{
  get
  {
    if (UserPrefs.ShowEmail)
      return User.Email;
    else
      return "Hidden";
  }
}
```

And now I've done the minimum required to go green (I change my mock `IUserPref`'s state and then query `UserProfileViewModel.Email`). Great; except when `UserPrefs` changes state internally due to other business logic, any view binding to `UserProfileViewModel.Email` is useless.

I can't notify `PropertyChanged` in the code above, because then that would no longer be the minimum required to make the test pass.

Question: Is there a clean way to make the test pass without a whole bunch of `PropertyChanged` handlers everywhere? PropertyChanged.Fody does help to some extent with stuff like this but not exactly this particular scenario.

Comment: @AdamVincent MVVM pattern is great. It's theory is awesome. Read my question and comments more carefully. It's how .Net 'implements' the patters that's rubbish. As my example very clearly shows, a unit test that checks property correctness does not mean a thing when it comes to that property being bound in .Net MVVM. Functional correctness does not directly mean View correctness, when it should, as this is precisely why there exists an intermediate presentation layer so that you don't have to test bindings, just the properties.

Comment: @AdamVincent It's because .Net's implementation of MVVM is rubbish that tools like Fody even exists. Another tool that could've solved my question is Update Controls, but it has limitations. I've researched these; clearly you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
Underlying data for the view model changes but the view model does not notify of the view of that change.

Solutions:
1) Create and bind to a new viewmodel with the latest underlying data.
2) Instead of exposing the underlying User class directly via the property. Create a backing _email variable that does raise propertychanged when updated and keep that in sync with the underlying data. So ViewModel.Email = UserPrefs.ShowEmail when UserPrefs gets updated by business logic.
3) Update UserPrefs to raise an Updated event you can use to raise PropertyChanged when the business logic updates UserPrefs.

*I can't notify PropertyChanged in the code above, because then that would no longer be the minimum required to make the test pass.*

Then make another test that tests notifying the UI that the data has changed.

Comment: I know how backing variables and `PropertyChanged` work, that's not my question. Point I'm trying to make is how rubbish .Net's implementation of MVVM is when it comes to writing minimal amount of code needed to satisfy specs. Another test just to make sure UI is notified, which offers no more insight into functional requirements than what my existing test already does, is just not on I'm afraid.